# Are all integers with exponent over 52 are even in 64 bit floating point

Tags: binary, floating-point

Am I correct to conclude that:

- all integers with exponent over 52 in the 64 bit floating point will be even? For example, if exponent is `53`, and the mantissa is `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, then the number is `100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010` - ends in `10`. If the mantissa is `54` the number ends with `100`.
- the more we increase the exponent, the more integer numbers can not be represented - for the exponent of `54` - it's impossible to represent one number - `9007199254740993`, with exponent of `55` - we can't represent `3` numbers (because we have two bits left out of mantissa which can have combinations of 01,10,11).

Comment: Possibly more suitable for http://stackoverflow.com/ (you're likely to get a faster answer there IMO).

Comment: @barakmanos, I asked [it there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304010/are-all-integers-with-exponent-over-52-are-even-in-64-bit-floating-point), but got no answer :)

Comment: Looks okay to me

Comment: @user251257, thanks :)